# prevent a user from connecting with different devices in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Is there any ways to detect whether a user has an active socket connection already? As far as I know, `socketId` is unique per device, not per user. What I need is that if `user1` connects from `device1` and then from `device2`, I don't allow him/her to connect from `device2` and show him/her the appropriate message. The point is that if `user1` disconnects from `device1` and the retry connecting from `device2`, I want him/her to connect from `device2` and no further from `device1`.

---

**edit 1** (more details of the scenario):

There is an android app where users can login freely from any number of devices with no limitations, but at some specific times, some games start that users can join them and play online with other users, but I want each user to see the game page only from one device and If he/she tries to join the game from the second device after joining from the first device, I want to prevent him/her from joining again as long as the first connection is active.

Thanks

Comment: Do users have to go through some login before you grant them a socket connection? Because having some independent way of correlating connections to users seems like the only way to do this. As you said socket connections are not per user.

Comment: @mb_s88 would you please check my post edit 1?

Comment: I don't see that you clearly answered my question. Do users log in before you grant them a socket connection? If no, I don't see a way to correlate users across connections, if yes, then use some information about their user to check for existing socket connections on other devices.

Comment: yes they login and wait for the game time. You mean something like an array to store userIDs who are online?